# Using Google maps api how to cmpare GPS coordinates(latti , longi) of two locations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

In an Android application I am struck in a problem any one have information about GPS coordinates from map , please help.

The problem is if I have coordinates(latitude and longitude) of two different points on Map and

I want to check that the points are on the same location on map 
Secondly are the two points are nearer to each other according to any criteria

For example .. if the point is in the 100m radius of the other point it seems to be nearer.

Comment: Location1.distanceTo(location2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use haversine formula to calculate two points,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final int R = 6371; // Radious of the earth
    Double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    Double lon1 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    Double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
    Double lon2 = Double.parseDouble(args[3]);
    Double latDistance = toRad(lat2-lat1);
    Double lonDistance = toRad(lon2-lon1);
    Double a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2) + 
               Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) * 
               Math.sin(lonDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2);
    Double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    Double distance = R * c;

    System.out.println("The distance between two lat and long is::" + distance);

}
```

You can compare this distance.This will do your job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I got your suggestion ...and it seems to be solution ...
but i am little bit confusing about this formula ... can u tell me about the haversine formula

Comment: Sure. Actually the code itself explains it all. Anyway, what else you want to know about this formula?